# Why does the object turn black in the Edit Mode?

Tags: materials

[image: Yellow Cone in OBJECT MODE]
This object looks fine in this mode. It has a shiny material on 2 selected faces.

[image: same Yellow Cone in EDIT MODE]
However, it turns black in this mode. It looks like wire, with hundreds of edges.

Answer (score 6):

You have an extremely large number of faces (and edges, and vertices). If you hit 'A' a few times in edit mode it will toggle orange/black/orange, etc.

Depending on what you intend to use this for, it may be far too many faces.

It is possible that you have a subdivision-surface modifier on this object, and the 'view subdivision' count is too high. Check your Modifiers tab to find out.

Comment: thx. i think ive done all you suggest. but it still remains and the count isnt high. i enlarged it to have a closer look and it looks like hundreds of wavy black lines and black dots?

Comment: @Kat   Well... now you've got me curious.  Can you provide a higher-resolution screenshot of your object, and perhaps any more details on what exactly you are seeing? Even better, if you can isolate that object into it's own .blend file and post it, I'm sure there are a number of folks here who might like to take a look.

Comment: thx, as soon as i figure out how to upload an image in Add Comment box :)